# The object is created double in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

When I upload a file, its record is created double or triple in Firestore database. I've checked again and again the addDoc function, but can not find what causes the problem, btw some double record has the same token after the url, some has different.

```
const useStorage = (file) => {
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)
const [error, setError] = useState(null)
const [url, setUrl] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {

    const storageRef = fbStorageRef(
        fbStorage, 
        "photo-gallery-reactjs/"+file.name
        );

    const uploadTask = fbUploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

    uploadTask.on('state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
            const progress = (
                snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes
                ) * 100;
            setProgress(progress)
        }, (error) => {
            setError(error)
        }, () => {
            fbGetDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                const createdAt = timestamp();
                const fileName = uploadTask.snapshot.ref.name;
                fbAddDoc(fbCollection(fbFirestore, "images"), {
                    downloadURL, createdAt, fileName
                })
                setUrl(downloadURL)
            })
        }
    )

}, [file])
return { progress, url, error }
```

}
export default useStorage;

Comment: Have you tried using a function that triggers when user clicks upload or so and then uploading the file instead of writing the whole logic directly in `useEffect()`?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I've tried but the result is the same, still creates the duplicate records

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code in useEffect:

```
// Cleanup function
    return () => {
      // Cancel the upload if the component unmounts
      uploadTask.cancel();
    };
  }, [file]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with links to documentation and/or explanation as to how this resolves the issue